# Pyspark and Log4J configuration

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, pyspark, log4j2

I'm trying to have some decent logging through Python using log4j.

I want to have all logs written to a DB, only errors written to an error.log file, and only info written to an info.log file.

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
lg = logger.LogManager.getRootLogger()
lg.info('test')
lg.error('test')
lg.debug('test')
lg.fatal('test')
```

and my log4j.properties file is as follow:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ria_info, ria_error, ria_mysql, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

# Set info logs to be written to info file
log4j.appender.ria_info=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ria_info.filter.RangeFilter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.ria_info.filter.RangeFilter.LevelToMatch=INFO
log4j.appender.ria_info.filter.RangeFilter.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.ria_info.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ria_info.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.ria_info.File=/home/data/logs/info.log
log4j.appender.ria_info.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.ria_info.MaxBackupIndex=10


log4j.appender.ria_error=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ria_error.Append=false
log4j.appender.ria_error.filter.RangeFilter=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter
log4j.appender.ria_error.filter.RangeFilter.LevelToMatch=ERROR
log4j.appender.ria_error.filter.RangeFilter.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.ria_error.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ria_error.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.appender.ria_error.File=/home/data/logs/error.log
log4j.appender.ria_error.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.ria_error.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.ria_mysql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.user=xxxx
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.password=xxxxx
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES('%p','%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%t','%x','%c','%m')
log4j.appender.ria_mysql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=INFO

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

Now I get the error and fatal 'test' message in my DB and error.log. But the info and debug message gets completely lost for some reason. Also `lg.isInfoEnabled()` returns False.

I tried a lot of stuff around additivity but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: `rootLogger=INFO` seems a good reason why you don't get any DEBUG...

Comment: True, but that doesn't explain why I don't get any INFO messages.

Comment: And I'm not sure what `logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=INFO` implies for the pyspark shell. BTW, you don't test WARN level, and don't want to store it - why? It's often very informative...

Comment: WARN level gets stored in the MYSQL DB normally as that stores all levels of logs.